# 'ValidatorAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jatnr.png)

```
FluentValidation.Attributes;
using MVC_Kutuphane_Otomasyonu.Entities.Validations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MVC_Kutuphane_Otomasyonu.Entities.Model
{
    [Validator(typeof(DuyurularValidator))]
    public class Duyurular
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Baslik { get; set; }
        public string Duyuru {  get; set; }
        public string Aciklama { get; set;}
        public DateTime Tarih {  get; set; }


    }
}
```

`[Validator(typeof(DuyurularValidator))]`I'm having trouble with the code in this line. I tried reinstalling all packages but I can't solve the problem. I'll be happy if you can help me

Comment: Suspect that you installed the wrong version/package FluentValidation as [Fluent Validation 8 only supports **ASP.NET MVC** (**not** ASP.NET **Core** MVC)](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/mvc5.html). Make sure you install [FluentValidation.Mvc5](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation-LegacyWeb/wiki/MVC-5-Integration). If you are using ASP.NET **Core**, please follow this [guideline](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received, "`ValidatorAttribute` does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument," might be due to the missing `using` directive for the `FluentValidation.Attributes`. Try:

```
using FluentValidation.Attributes;
```

Comment: It says method, but I made a mistake while adding it here. Normally there is using in the code. It's never works